# StackView size change for different orientation

Tags: swift, xcode, uistackview

[image: The stack view for the portrait mode seems to work just the way i designed]

[image: landscape of the same view]

So, stack view of the contents seems to be aligned the way I designed them in the portrait mode. However, I the landscape mode the buttons seems to be stretching a lot. is there a way I could set up constraints that only work on these objects while in the landscape mode.

thanks,

Comment: You can try to use Size Classes to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different sizes of Stackview objects for different orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375386/different-sizes-of-stackview-objects-for-different-orientation)

Comment: You can change the `spacing` of the stackview on orientation change